# Java Micro Edition 3.2 SDK replacement for BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, sdk, bufferedoutputstream

The Java Micro Edition SDK does not include java.io.BufferedOutputStream. Does anyone know of a suitable replacement which is present within the SDK?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a replacement, but BufferedOutputStream doesn't contain much code. Just duplicate it from the full blown JDK source to your own replacement class. There is no rocket science in the class anyway.